# Logic issue - double refresh of content

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Working through the 100 Days of SwiftUI I have completed somehow the Milestone: Projects 4-6 (for ref. :https://www.hackingwithswift.com/100/swiftui/35), which seems to work ok apart from a logic bug that I have obviously inadvertently created, which caused a double refresh of the question, once after providing the answer and once again after tapping the continue button on the alert window. I would be extremely helpful if you could help me understanding what I did wrong on this specific issue.

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Ammo.

---

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var multiplier: Int = 1
    var numberOfQuestions = [5, 10, 12]
    @State private var chosenNumberOfQuestions = 0
    @State private var tableScale = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12].shuffled()
    @State private var counter = 1
    @State private var score = 0
    @State private var scoreTitle = ""
    @State private var showingScore = false
    @State private var finalMessage = ""
    @State private var showingFinalMessage = false
    
    private var tableScaleRandom = [Int]()
    
    
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Text("❎").font(.largeTitle)
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            Spacer()
            Text("Multiplication Challenge  ")
                .font(.largeTitle)
            
            Spacer()
            Text("Choose the multiplication table to test")
            
            Stepper("Multiplication table .. \(multiplier)", value: $multiplier, in: 1...12){_ in
                tableScale.shuffle()
            }
            
            Text("Number of questions").font(.title)
            Picker("Number of questions", selection: $chosenNumberOfQuestions) {
                ForEach(numberOfQuestions, id: \.self) {
                    
                    Text("\($0)")
                       .font(.title)
         
                    

                }
            }.pickerStyle(.segmented)
            
            Text("\(multiplier) X \(tableScale[0]) =").opacity(chosenNumberOfQuestions != 0 ? 1 : 0)
            let result = multiplication(a: multiplier, b: tableScale[0])
            let arrayOfNumbers = generateTwoRandomNumbers(correctAnswer: result)
            ForEach(arrayOfNumbers.shuffled(), id: \.self) { number in
                
               
                Button {
                    numberTapped(number: number, result: result)
                    
                } label: {
                 Text("\(number)").opacity(chosenNumberOfQuestions != 0 ? 1 : 0)
                    
                }
                
                Spacer()
            }
            
            
                
             
        }.alert(scoreTitle, isPresented: $showingScore) {
            Button("Continue", action: askAnotherQuestion)
        } message: {
            Text("Your score is: \(score)")
        }.alert(finalMessage, isPresented: $showingFinalMessage) {
            Button("Start again", action: resetGame)
        } message: {
            Text("Your score is: \(score)")
        }
        .padding()
        
    }
    
    func askAnotherQuestion() {
        tableScale.shuffle()
    }
    
    func multiplication(a: Int, b: Int) -> Int {
        let result = a * b
        return result
    }

    func generateTwoRandomNumbers(correctAnswer: Int) -> [Int] {
        
        let a = Int.random(in: 0...144)
        let b = Int.random(in: 0...144)
        
        let arrayOfRandomNumbers = [correctAnswer, a, b]
        
        return arrayOfRandomNumbers
    }

    func numberTapped(number: Int, result: Int){
        
        if counter < chosenNumberOfQuestions {
            
            if number == result {
                
                scoreTitle = "\(number) is correct! This is your try no. \(counter)"
                counter += 1
                score += 1
                
                print("Hello")
            } else {
                counter += 1
                score -= 1
                
                scoreTitle = "Wrong. The right result is \(result)"
            }
            showingScore = true
        } else if counter == chosenNumberOfQuestions {
            
            if number == result {
                
                scoreTitle = "\(number) is correct! This is your try no. \(counter)"
                counter += 1
                score += 1
                
                print("Hello")
            } else {
                counter += 1
                score -= 1
                
                scoreTitle = "Wrong. The right result is \(result)"
            }
            showingFinalMessage = true
            if score == chosenNumberOfQuestions {
                finalMessage = "Great!"
            } else if score > (score / 2) {
                finalMessage = "Well done!"
            } else {
                finalMessage = "Too bad!!!"
            }
        }
    }
    func resetGame() {
        counter = 1
        score = 0
        multiplier = 1
        chosenNumberOfQuestions = 0
        tableScale.shuffle()
        
    }
   
}





struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

In the "app" the user select the one answer between the three offered and is presented with the alert message which gives him a fedback on the correctness of his anwer and at the tap of the "Continue" button a new set of Question and Answers gets presented. Somehow a double refresh of the question and answers happens, once after providing the answer and once again after tapping the continue button on the alert window.

Comment: do u need ```tableScale.shuffle()``` inside Stepper() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is these 3 lines of code:

```
let result = multiplication(a: multiplier, b: tableScale[0])
let arrayOfNumbers = generateTwoRandomNumbers(correctAnswer: result)
ForEach(arrayOfNumbers.shuffled(), id: \.self) { number in
```

You should not be computing values in your view code.  Every time your view redraws, it is computing new values.  You want to control that outside of the view code.

How to fix:

1. `result` and `arrayOfNumbers` should be `@State vars`.
2. Move the code to compute the `result`, `generateTwoNumbers` and `shuffle` the `arrayOfNumbers` into `askAnotherQuestion`.
3. You'll need to call `askAnotherQuestion` in your `Stepper`.
4. You'll need to trigger an initial `askAnotherQuestion` at startup.  Perhaps inside of an `.onAppear()` modifier.

Comment: Wow, that is great. Super detailed analisys. Thanks a million for your help and explaination.

Comment: Thanks again vacawama. I have just implemented your suggestion and works great. Thanks again for sharing your time and knowledge.